# Should I own the site that I create Chrome Web App for?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome Web App for some WebSite.

I noticed - [at Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) - Google requires me to own the site in the `web_url`:

```
"launch": {"web_url": "http://example.org/"}
```

Error Msg:

```
This hosted web app specifies a web_url that is not matched by sites you own. Before you can publish this app, you must verify ownership of the web_url listed below.
Unmatched web_url
```

Comment: What exactly is your question.  The error message is clear.  If you provide a web_url you must own the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, you must own the sites for Chrome Apps that you *upload to the Chrome Web Store*.  There is nothing stopping you from creating a Web app for a site you don't own and then offering the CRX file on your own site or any other 3rd party file hosting service.

The restriction exists within Google's Web Store, not the browser itself.

Answer (score 17):

Common errors on attempting to publish an app to the Chrome WebStore.

- The official website was not valid.
- The web_url of this hosted web app is not owned by the developer.

I answered a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/drive/-/eAmhHsP4a7kJ.).

I set the value of web_url in the manifest to

1. sites.google.com/site/conjointbiz
2. semanticc.blogspot.co.uk
3. [www.conjoint.biz](http://www.conjoint.biz)/

in turn. I am actually (obviously) only the registrant of 3.
It seems that by own, google mean registrant.

The following reflects my lack of knowledge and, therefore, inability to give a fuller answer.
The question is raised as to what happens behind the scenes to check ownership. And what exactly constitutes ownership?
I am currently unclear how a company that owns a web site devolves that ownership to a developer who works for that company. That is what the process of developer registration is in this case?
Nor how I "may request they [the site owner] grant you an association which allows you to publish apps ... "

Does anyone know?

This is my previous post:-
I actually do not own the URL of sites.google.com/site/conjointbiz although it is 'my' web site. It was created for me by BT/Google initiative and I used it as it is one I could modify into an app home page. So, not before I own that URL.
It may be that semanticc.blogspot.co.uk/ a blogger blog would also represent the same problem?
I do own the other URLs that I can use e.g. www.conjoint.biz

...